# Problems when running Python script from java

Tags: java, python, shell, imagemagick-convert

I am running a simple Python script from Java. The code for this is shown below

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] command = {"python", "python_script_path.py"};
        System.out.println(command);

        ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        ps.redirectErrorStream(true);

        try {
            Process pr = ps.start();  

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            pr.waitFor();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And, my Python script

```
command = '/opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert ' + 'path_to_some_file.pdf' + ' ' + 'path_to_some_file.png'
os.system(command)
```

Even though, when the Python script is run from the terminal, the script is working perfectly, but when called from java, I get an error :

```
convert: no images defined `path_to_some_file.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.
```

I have no clue why this is the case. Please help.

Comment: Are you specifying the full pathname to `some_file.pdf`, or just the plain filename?  If the latter, it's going to look for that file in the current directory (wherever that is for the java program.)

Comment: @JohnGordon I am specifying the full path of the files

Comment: @JohnGordon in my actual case, I get the error `convert: no images defined '/Volumes/jarvis/Documents/temp.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this:

Use the full path to image Magick in the Python script